# completely reducible module iff intersection of maximal submodules is trivial

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-groups, representation-theory

Let $V$ be a finite dimensional $A$-module where $A$ is a finite dimensional algebra. I want to show that $V$ is completely reducible (semi-simple) if and only the intersection of all the maximal submodules (Jacobson radical?) is trivial.

## My Thoughts...

Assuming $V$ is completely reducible we can write $V$ as

$$V=\dot\sum^n V_i$$

where the $V_i$ are irreducible for all $i$. I was thinking originally that all the maximal submodules could be generated by taking any $n-1$ components of the above sum and looking at their sum. However, this doesn't seem credible to me.

I can conclude that any maximal submodule must either completely contain or trivially intersect any of the irreducible submodules and each irreducible submodule must be contained in some maximal submodule (because duh). I do believe that any $n-1$ of the irreducible submodules must be maximal (as otherwise writing the module as an n-tuple I would find a proper submodule of an irreducible submodule). The intersection of these $n$ maximal submodules must be trivial as it can be written as

$$V_1 \cap V_2 \cap \dots \cap V_n \cap \text{some other stuff} = \{0\}$$

We can conclude then the intersection of all maximal submodules, which must be contained in the above, must be trivial.

I'm not sure about the converse direction. I'm not really looking for an answer more a kind of a push in the right direction.

Comment: One way to do this is to think about the way to embed V into some semisimple module. (Submodules of semisimple modules are also semisimple!) Let me know if you want another hint.

Comment: Does what I suggested above not work?
I've thought about embedding V in some irreducible module as Isaacs suggests but it's not clicking for me. What I'm thinking is it must be something like looking at the V as the sum of irreducibles which are themselves factor modules (quotients) of the regular algebra $A^\circ$.

Comment: Sorry, your suggestion above is indeed OK. I was talking about the other direction,  $J(V) = 0$ implies semisimplicity. Try thinking about irreducible modules of the form $V/M$ where $M$ is a maximal submodule of $V$.

Comment: If you have some finite collection $M_1, \ldots, M_n$ of maximal submodules of $V$, when is the natural homomorphism $V \to \bigoplus_{i=1}^n V/M_i$ a monomorphism? I hope I'm not giving too much away.

Comment: It's a monomorphism exactly when it is an isomorphism I think. Since the natural homomorphism is already surjective. But can we gaurantee that. Right now, all I see is that the intersection being empty forces that sum to be direct (though I feel shaky on that now)

Comment: I really don't have any more hints to give... just be careful, that map isn't automatically surjective as you say. It isn't really important for this topic, but I have to mention it. Also, nothing "forces" that sum to be direct... it is direct by definition (that's what $\oplus$ means, direct sum).

Comment: If you want to check out a complete proof, this blog post https://mathstrek.blog/2015/01/09/radical-of-module/ has it. Actually it proves a bit more, that an Artinian module with its radical zero is semisimple. In your case, finite dimension of your module implies that it's Artinian.

Comment: Sorry I didn't mean to say direct. I meant internal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose that $V$ is completely reducible and $0\neq W$ be the intersection of all of the maximal submodules of $V$. Then let $W\oplus U=V$, from $W\cap U=0$ we know that $W\not\subset U$ hence $U$ is not maximal. So $U$ is contained in a maximal submodule by finite dimensionality, namely $U\subset V'$, hence $W\oplus V'\subsetneq V$, contradiction.
Conversely, suppose that the intersection of all of the maximal submodule of $V$ is trivial, then the natural homomorphism $V\rightarrow \oplus_{i=1}^nV/M_i$ is injective where $V/M_i$ is irreducible. So $V$ is completely reducible, as a submodule of a completely reducible module.

Comment: How did you conclude that a finite collection of maximal submodules suffices to intersect to $\{0\}$? This deserves a comment. (I know an easy way, I'm just asking to draw attention to the situation.) It is necessary to establish this to conclude that the suggested homomorphism (into the *product* of $V/M$'s) is also into the direct sum.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how to conclude this. Could you tell me?

Comment: Since $V$ is finite dimensional, it's Artinian, and Artinian modules have that property.

Answer (score 0):

If $V$ is irreducible, we are done. Otherwise, let $W_1$ be a non-zero proper irreducible submodule of $V$. Since the intersection of all maximal submodules is zero, there must exist a maximal submodule $V_1$ such that $W_1 \not \subset V_1$. Then $V = W_1 \oplus V_1$.

If $V_1$ is irreducible, we are done.  Otherwise, repeat the above process as follows: let $W_2$ be a non-zero proper irreducible submodule of $V_1$, and choose a maximal $U_2$ such that $W_2 \not \subset U_2$. Then check that $V_1 = W_2 \oplus V_2$ where $V_2 = U_2 \cap V_1$.

If $V_2$ is irreducible, we are done, else repeat as above. Since $V$ is finite dimensional, this process terminates and we conclude that $V$ is completely reducible.